# creating random list of names in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I'm using spark/scala to generate about 10 mln people in a CSV file on HDFS by randomly mixing 2 csv files with first and lastname + adding a date of birth random between 1920 and now + creation data + counter.

I'm running into a bit of a problem using a for loop everything is working correctly but in that case the loop part only runs on the driver and this seems to be limited to working fine on 1 mln, generating 10 mln takes about 10 minutes longer. So I decided to create a range with 10 mln items so I could use map and utilize the cluster. I got the following code:

```
package ebicus
import org.apache.spark._
import org.joda.time.{DateTime,Interval,LocalDateTime}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import java.util.Random

   object main_generator_spark {
   val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("Generator")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)         

   val rs = Random            
   val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://host:8020/user/firstname")
   val fnames = file.flatMap(line => line.split("\n")).map(x => x.split(",")(1))

   val fnames_ar = fnames.collect()
   val fnames_size = fnames_ar.length
   val firstnames = sc.broadcast(fnames_ar)

   val file2 = sc.textFile("hdfs://host:8020/user/lastname")
   val lnames = file2.flatMap(line => line.split("\n")).map(x => x.split(",")(1))
   val lnames_ar =  lnames.collect()
   val lnames_size = lnames_ar.length
   val lastnames = sc.broadcast(lnames_ar)

   val range_val = sc.range(0, 100000000, 1, 20)

   val rddpersons = range_val.map(x =>
                            (x.toString, 
                            new DateTime().toString("y-M-d::H:m:s"),
 **Error at line 77-->      fnames_ar(rs.nextInt(fnames_size)),** 
                            lnames_ar(rs.nextInt(lnames_size)),
                            makeGebDate
                            )
      )

   def makeGebDate():String ={
     lazy val start = new DateTime(1920,1,1,0,0,0)
     lazy val end = new DateTime().minusYears(18)
     lazy val hours = (new Interval(start, end).toDurationMillis()./(1000*60*60)).toInt
     start.plusHours(rs.nextInt(hours)).toString("y-MM-dd")
   }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {      
     rddpersons.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://hdfs://host:8020/user/output")
 }
```

The code works fine when I use the spark-shell but when I try to run the script with a spark-submit (I'm using maven to build):

```
spark-submit --class ebicus.main_generator_spark --num-executors 16 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 2G --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 10g /u01/stage/mvn_test-0.0.2.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2(saveAsTextFile at main_generator_sprak.scala:93)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[11] at saveAsTextFile at main_generator_sprak.scala:93), which has no missing parents
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(140536) called with curMem=1326969, maxMem=5556991426
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6 stored as values in memory (estimated size 137.2 KB, free 5.2 GB)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(48992) called with curMem=1467505, maxMem=5556991426
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_6_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 47.8 KB, free 5.2 GB)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on 10.29.7.4:51642 (size: 47.8 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 6 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 20 missing tasks from ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[11] at saveAsTextFile at main_generator_sprak.scala:93)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 2.0 with 20 tasks
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 8, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 9, cloudera-003.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 1,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 10, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 2,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, cloudera-003.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 3,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 4,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 13, cloudera-003.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 5,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 14, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 6,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 15, cloudera-003.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 7,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on cloudera-003.fusion.ebicus.com:52334 (size: 47.8 KB, free: 1060.2 MB)
16/06/16 11:17:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_6_piece0 in memory on cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com:53110 (size: 47.8 KB, free: 1060.2 MB)
16/06/16 11:17:30 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 16, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 8,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:30 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 17, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com, partition 9,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2029 bytes)
16/06/16 11:17:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 14, cloudera-001.fusion.ebicus.com): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ebicus.main_generator_spark$
        at ebicus.main_generator_spark$$anonfun$5.apply(main_generator_sprak.scala:77)
        at ebicus.main_generator_spark$$anonfun$5.apply(main_generator_sprak.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1205)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm I making some kind of fundamental thinking error? I would be happy if someone can point me in a direction?

Edit: I'm using cloudera 5.6.0, spark 1.5.0, scala 2.10.6, yarn 2.10, joda-time 2.9.4

Edit2: Added conf & sc

Comment: Why are you putting all your code out of the main function? Anyway, where do you define the sc variable (i.e. the SparkContext)?

Comment: I added the SparkConfig and context, it's in his format because it is actually part of a bigger script but I broke it down to the error part.

Comment: The exception indicates that the classes cannot be loaded on the executors. I think that with `spark-submit` you need to indicate that your jar should be broadcasted to the cluster using: `--jars path/to/mycode.jar

Comment: Thnks, I guess that is something like: 
spark-submit --class ebicus.main_generator_spark --num-executors 16 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 2G --jars /u01/stage/mvn_test-0.0.2.jar --driver-cores 2 --driver-memory 10g /u01/stage/mvn_test-0.0.2.jar. I also tried using hdfs dir as a source for the jar files: still get the same error

Comment: Also tried to add sc.addJar("hdfs://host:8020/user/mvn_test-0.0.2.jar") in the code

Comment: The problem is that there is an exception while loading the object, i.e. while executing all the code which is not inside any method. I don't know which is the line 74, if you can point it out, it could be easier to understand which is the problem.

Comment: Oh sure, didn't think of that uhmm the problem is in the loop at     fnames_ar(rs.nextInt(fnames_size)). So the first time it referes to a val out of the loop. (tried this.fnames_ar already). Loop works great if I put in some strings instead. Also, if I only use the makeGebDate function in the loop it has the same error

Comment: maybe it's due to the fact that not everything of the object is yet loaded, can you try to move the code in the main method?

Comment: Ok, it is something with the class loading in the actors. Running the sparkconfig with setMaster("local[2]") works correctly